# Act on image loading without loading twice

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I am loading an image and displaying once the image is finished and various css and animations are complete. But I want to call the image to check width and height within the the function:

```
$('.ePage').find('img').each(function(){
    var $img    = $(this);
    $('<img/>').load(function(){

         // my css and animations
         // need to check height and width


    }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
});
```

Only I dont want to load the image twice. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ePage').find('img').each(function(){
    var $img    = $(this);
    $('<img/>').load(function(){

         console.log($(this).css("width"));
         console.log($(this).css("height"));
         console.log($(this).width());
         console.log($(this).height());

    }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/css/
- http://api.jquery.com/width/
- http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Yep, seems I was having a total mental block. I was throwing in the $img.width() and $img.height() after a function that edited the height. Time for a break I think. Thanks for the help karim79 :)